# Replace all files except one with rsync

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, rsync

I'm currently using `rsync` as follows

```
rsync -az --delete ...
```

What option can I use with `rsync` to replace all destination files that already exist except for one specific file that should not be replaced if already exists? Sure, if the file doesn't exist at the destination, it should be put there.

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on [su]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether it is possible in one invocation, but you could call rsync twice:

`rsync ... --ignore-existing file dest`

Now the file is put there if it didn't exist before.

`rsync ... --exclude file src dest`

Now all the other files are handled as usual, except for the one excluded file.

Comment: It sure works, pity not very elegant though.